# What should be the straightforward definition of" with" in the sentence " I talked about the problem with my tutor."?

Tags: prepositions, definition, interpretation

I talked about the problem *with* my tutor.

I think it could mean "involving somebody as a participant".Am I correct?I want suggestions.Thanks

Comment: You mean the talk involving someone, or the problem involving someone?

Comment: @StuartF I talked about the problem involving my tutor as a participant.

Comment: @StuartF the talk involving someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken out of context, your sentence is ambiguous.
"I have a problem with my course work so I discussed it with my tutor."
or
"My tutor is not holding tutorials so I discussed it with the professor."
In either case **with** could be said to mean **involving somebody as a participant** but IMHO you are overthinking it. I both cases you just met with your tutor/professor to talk about a problem.